How to use Jflex to generate a lexer properly?
I was told that making lexer from scrath is really hard and that we should use built in libraries. I used an already existing example to build my program. It worked but was full of error partially because of my lexer. TA told me right away to use a built in library like JFlex. I have been trying to learn that, but nothing is really working (is it normal that the generated file is 700 lines?) for me. It feels like learning Jflex is harder than creating a lexer. Can someone help me with this, it  won't compile after being generated.
Quick summary: I wanna make a lexer for Turtle. I want to use my lexer to peek next token, to go to next token, keep track of my rows and as well as matching key words. I'd really appreciate it, if someone could shine a light here.
import java.lang.System;
import java_cup.runtime.Symbol;

%%
%cup
%class Lex

%{

private int rowCounter = 1;

public int getRow() {
    return rowCounter;
}   

%}

%%
"." { return new Symbol(sym.PERIOD); }
"\"" { return new Symbol(sym.QUOTE); }
"#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}" { return new Symbol(sym.HEX); }
[0-9]+ { return new Symbol(sym.DECIMAL, Integer.parseInt(yytext())); }
"FORW" { return new Symbol(sym.FORW); }
"BACK" { return new Symbol(sym.BACK); }
"LEFT" { return new Symbol(sym.LEFT); }
"RIGHT" { return new Symbol(sym.RIGHT); }
"UP" { return new Symbol(sym.UP); }
"DOWN" { return new Symbol(sym.DOWN); }
"COLOR" { return new Symbol(sym.COLOR); }
"REP" { return new Symbol(sym.REP); }
"%" { /* Ignore comments */ }
"\n" { return new Symbol(sym.NEWLINE); }
<<EOF>> { return new Symbol(sym.EOF); }
[ \t\n] { }


Coding and implementation questions are off-topic here, so I suspect the community might view this question as out of scope.  Any votes from community members?

It seems like a similar question has been asked on SO.

Have you had a look at the user manual?
There's a section that walks you through a full example and on how to get it build.

@Knogger Not that sepcific one (I will check it out now) but I have followed different examples and even from my lectures and went thru the documentation. I was told it is easier to generate a lexer using a library than to make it myself but seems like no matter what I try I cannot generate anything useful. Looking at this what what do you think is wrong?

@D.W Oh sorry I didn't know. Do I delete it now?
